# MySQL: How to pass a column name as parameter in MySQL query

Tags: mysql, parameters, names, workbench

Shows all cities containing "a" :

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE city LIKE '%a%';  -- works fine
```

**What is the correct syntax :**

```
SET @param = 'city';
SELECT * FROM user WHERE @param LIKE '%a%'; -- NOT yielding any rows
```

*Tested in MySQL Workbench query*

Comment: You need to use [13.5 Prepared SQL Statement Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html).

Answer (score 2):

**The correct syntax goes like this:**

```
SET @param = 'city';
SET @statement = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM user WHERE ', @param, ' LIKE ', '"%a%"');
PREPARE myquery FROM @statement;
EXECUTE myquery;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE myquery
```

Things to keep in mind:

1. put spaces in the CONCAT params in line#2 where necessary as CONCAT won't put them for you, e.g. you (and MySQL also) would prefer :

> ... user WHERE city LIKE '%a%';

rather than :

> ... userWHEREcityLIKE'%a%'

2. add extra AND different quotes :

> '%a%' should become '"%a%"'

3. DEALLOCATE in the end - you declared a global var 'myquery' valid by default till the session reset - may cause collisions and errors
4. **Tip** To see the result of CONCAT(), use

> SELECT @statement

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
select id,date,@statement as any_name from table_name ;
SET @statement = (SELECT To_days( date_f ) - TO_DAYS( date )  FROM `table_name `);
```